# How to check if file=$1 exist?

Tags: bash, scripting

I have this task to do:

> Check if a file with provided parameter (file=$1) exist

When I put this code below it is saying that "File doesn't exist" what is not true because I have a file named "1". Could someone please tell me what I did incorrectly?

```
file=$1 

if [ -f $file ]
then
  echo "File $file exist"
else
  echo "File $file doesn't exist"
  fi
```

Comment: How did you run this script? The location where you run the code is important if $1 is a relative path. You can also use absolutely path if you don't want to care about the location.

Comment: The syntax `$1` doesn't refer to a file named `"1"`, it refers to the first command line parameter of your script. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters).

Comment: Good you have file named `1`. But most important, which is the first parameter of your script? Because this is what you will be checking.

Comment: thank you guys, now I get it :)